# Not able to get the query result with SQLDescribeCol()/SQLBindCol()

Tags: database, odbc

```cpp
int ODBCDatabase::GetTableOwner(const std::wstring &schemaName, const std::wstring &tableName, std::wstring &tableOwner, std::vector<std::wstring> &errorMsg)

{
    SQLHSTMT stmt = 0;
    SQLHDBC hdbc = 0;
    int result = 0;
    SQLLEN cbTableName = SQL_NTS, cbSchemaName = SQL_NTS;
    SQLWCHAR *table_name = NULL, *schema_name = NULL, *qry = NULL;
    SQLWCHAR *owner = NULL;
    std::wstring query;
    if( pimpl->m_subtype == L"Microsoft SQL Server" )
        query = L"SELECT cast(su.name AS nvarchar(128)) FROM sysobjects so, sysusers su, sys.tables t, sys.schemas s WHERE so.uid = su.uid AND t.object_id = so.id AND t.schema_id = s.schema_id AND s.name = ? AND so.name = ?;";
    SQLRETURN retcode = SQLAllocHandle( SQL_HANDLE_DBC, m_env, &hdbc );
    if( retcode != SQL_SUCCESS && retcode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO )
    {
        GetErrorMessage( errorMsg, 0 );
        result = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        SQLSMALLINT OutConnStrLen;
        retcode = SQLDriverConnect( hdbc, NULL, m_connectString, SQL_NTS, NULL, 0, &OutConnStrLen, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT );
        if( retcode != SQL_SUCCESS && retcode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO )
        {
            GetErrorMessage( errorMsg, 2, hdbc );
            result = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            retcode = SQLAllocHandle( SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hdbc, &stmt );
            if( retcode != SQL_SUCCESS && retcode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO )
            {
                GetErrorMessage( errorMsg, 2, hdbc );
                result = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                table_name = new SQLWCHAR[tableName.length() + 2];
                schema_name = new SQLWCHAR[schemaName.length() + 2];
                qry = new SQLWCHAR[query.length() + 2];
                memset( qry, '\0', query.size() + 2 );
                memset( table_name, '\0', tableName.length() + 2 );
                memset( schema_name, '\0', schemaName.length() + 2 );
                uc_to_str_cpy( qry, query );
                uc_to_str_cpy( table_name, tableName );
                uc_to_str_cpy( schema_name, schemaName );
                retcode = SQLPrepare( stmt, qry, SQL_NTS );
                if( retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO )
                {
                    retcode = SQLBindParameter( stmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_WCHAR, SQL_WCHAR, schemaName.length(), 0, schema_name, 0, &cbSchemaName );
                    if( retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO )
                    {
                        retcode = SQLBindParameter( stmt, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_WCHAR, SQL_WCHAR, tableName.length(), 0, table_name, 0, &cbTableName );
                        if( retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO )
                        {
                            retcode = SQLExecute( stmt );
                            if( retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO )
                            {
                                SQLSMALLINT nameBufLength, dataTypePtr, decimalDigitsPtr, isNullable;
                                SQLULEN columnSizePtr;
                                SQLLEN cbTableOwner;
                                retcode = SQLDescribeCol( stmt, 1, NULL, 0, &nameBufLength, &dataTypePtr, &columnSizePtr, &decimalDigitsPtr, &isNullable );
                                if( retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO )
                                {
                                    owner = new SQLWCHAR[columnSizePtr + 1];
                                    retcode = SQLBindCol( stmt, 1, SQL_C_WCHAR, &owner, columnSizePtr, &cbTableOwner );
                                    if( retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO )
                                    {
                                        retcode = SQLFetch( stmt );
                                        if( retcode != SQL_SUCCESS && retcode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO && retcode != SQL_NO_DATA )
                                        {
                                            GetErrorMessage( errorMsg, 1, stmt );
                                            result = 1;
                                        }
                                        if( retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO )
                                            str_to_uc_cpy( tableOwner, owner );
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if( pimpl->m_subtype == L"Microsoft SQL Server" )
                                        {
                                            tableOwner = L"dbo";
                                            result = 0;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            GetErrorMessage( errorMsg, 1, stmt );
                                            result = 1;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else if( retcode != SQL_NO_DATA )
                                {
                                    GetErrorMessage( errorMsg, 1, stmt );
                                    result = 1;
                                }
                            }
                            else if( retcode != SQL_NO_DATA )
                            {
                                GetErrorMessage( errorMsg, 1, stmt );
                                result = 1;
                            }
                        }
                        else if( retcode != SQL_NO_DATA )
                        {
                            GetErrorMessage( errorMsg, 1, stmt );
                            result = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    else if( retcode != SQL_NO_DATA )
                    {
                        GetErrorMessage( errorMsg, 1, stmt );
                        result = 1;
                    }
                }
                else if( retcode != SQL_NO_DATA )
                {
                    GetErrorMessage( errorMsg, 1, stmt );
                    result = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if( stmt )
    {
        retcode = SQLFreeHandle( SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt );
        if( retcode != SQL_SUCCESS && retcode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO )
        {
            GetErrorMessage( errorMsg, 1, stmt );
            result = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            stmt = 0;
            retcode = SQLDisconnect( hdbc );
            if( retcode != SQL_SUCCESS && retcode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO )
            {
                GetErrorMessage( errorMsg, 1, stmt );
                result = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                retcode = SQLFreeHandle( SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hdbc );
                if( retcode != SQL_SUCCESS && retcode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO )
                {
                    GetErrorMessage( errorMsg, 1, stmt );
                    result = 1;
                }
                else
                    hdbc = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    delete qry;
    qry = NULL;
    delete table_name;
    table_name = NULL;
    delete schema_name;
    schema_name = NULL;
    delete owner;
    owner = NULL;
    return result;
}
```

The code above compiles and executes fine. However even though SQLFetch() returns the record, the data is not available.

Can anyone spot an error? It is the first time I'm using SQDescribeCol()/SQLBindCol() pair and something is definitely is wrong here.

An ODBC API direct usage is because the program is cross-platform/cross-database. AFAIK, this is the only technology available to do it like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```c
SQLWCHAR *owner = NULL;
...
SQLBindCol( stmt, 1, SQL_C_WCHAR, &owner, columnSizePtr, &cbTableOwner );
```

You are giving the address of the pointer, so the pointer itself gets overwritten.

Comment: Thank you. Getting rid of `&` fixed it. Now I'm curious why the compiler didn't report it as an error, because according to MSDN this should be a SQLPOINTER. But that's a question for another time. Thank you.